# Object constructor within another constructor?

Tags: c++, object, constructor, initializer-list

I'm still fresh to CPP and I'm trying new things with all this free time we have currently. I have 2 separate classes and I want to create an initializer list for both in main... May'be I'm not putting it in the best words, but...

There's this:

```
class Status
{
public:
    int x, y;
    float angle;
    unsigned short hp;
    bool isActive;
    Status(const int _x, const int _y, const float _angle, const unsigned short _hp, bool _isActive)
        : x(_x), y(_y), angle(_angle), hp(_hp), isActive(_isActive){};
};
```

And this:

```
class Hero
{
    std::string name;
    Status status;
    Hero(const std::string _name, Status &status)
        : name(_name), status(x, y, angle, hp, isActive){}; 
    void display()
    {
        std::cout << "Hero:\t" << name << std::endl;
        std::cout << "HP:\t" << Hero::status.hp << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Hero is " << Hero::status.isActive ? " active" : " inactive";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    };
```

...and I ultimately want to do something like this...
`Hero h = {"Iron Man", {1, 2, 32.9, 100, true}};`

Please guide me, o wise ones...

Comment: `Hero` constructor won't compile. It references names `x`, `y` and so on that are not declared in that scope.

Comment: ...how to set up the Hero class constructor to set the hero and status members in an initializer list on instantiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
Hero(const std::string _name, Status &status)
    : name(_name), status(x, y, angle, hp, isActive){};
```

should be:

```
Hero(const std::string _name, Status status)
    : name(_name), status(status){};
```

Optionally it could be `status(std::move(status))` .

Also there is a logic error on the line with the conditional operator  which has higher precedence than `<<` so you need some parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. First you can't use the `Status` member variables directly. To solve this you either need to access them normally as in

   ```
   Hero(const std::string _name, Status &_status)
       : name(_name), status(_status.x, _status.y, _status.angle, _status.hp, _status.isActive)
   {}
   ```

   Or you could just rely on the automatically generated copy-constructor:

   ```
   Hero(const std::string _name, Status &_status)
       : name(_name), status(_status)
   {}
   ```
2. The second problem is that the expression `{1, 2, 32.9, 100, true}` results in a so-called *rvalue* which can't be captured by normal references. You either need to use rvalue-references, `const` references, or plain non-reference values. I really recommend the latter:

   ```
   Hero(const std::string _name, Status _status)
       : name(_name), status(_status)
   {}
   ```